# How can i simplify the following formula: $\sum\limits_{i,j=1}^{n}(t_{j}\land t_{i})$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus, summation, induction

Consider the following time discretization $t_{0}=0< t_{1} < ... < t_{n} = T$ of $[0,T]$ where the time increments are equal in magnitude, i.e. $t_{j}-t_{j-1}=\delta$.

How can i simplify the following formula: $\sum\limits_{i,j=1}^{n}(t_{j}\land t_{i})$?

Note that $a\land b := \min (a,b)$

My attempt:

$\sum\limits_{i,j=1}^{n}(t_{j}\land t_{i})= \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}(t_{j}\land t_{i})$

Consider $i=1$:

$\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}(t_{j}\land t_{1})=nt_{1}$

Consider $i=2$:

$\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}(t_{j}\land t_{2})=(n-1)t_{2}+t_{1}$

Consider $i=3$:

$\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}(t_{j}\land t_{2})=(n-2)t_{3}+t_{2}+t_{1}$

...

Continuing as above, I would obtain:

$$ \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}(t_{j}\land t_{i})=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\left((n+1-i)t_{i}+\sum\limits_{j=1}^{i-1}t_{j}\right)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\left((n+1-i)t_{i}+\delta(i-1)\right)$$

Surely, this is not the best simplification there is?

Comment: Hint: since they form an arithmetic progression. $t_i\wedge t_j=\min(i,j)\delta$. Your expression should be some polynomial of $n$ times $\delta$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $(t_j\wedge t_i)$ populate a $n \times n$ symmetric matrix with a distinct pattern (try to draw it). You have
$$\begin{aligned}
&t_1(1+2(n-1))\\
&t_2(1+2(n-2))\\
&(...)\\
&t_{n-1}(1+2)\\
&t_n
\end{aligned}$$
Since $\delta =t_j-t_{j-1}$ we have that the sum of all the matrix components is
$$\sum_{i,j}(t_i\wedge t_j)=\sum_{1\leq k\leq n}\delta k(1+2(n-k))=\delta\bigg(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+n^2(n+1)-\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{3}\bigg)$$
which possibly con be written more succintly even.